# Text input placeholders are broken in latest version of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, google-chrome

Sorry I can't provide anymore information on the issue other than a screenshot, I've currently got no way to test on Windows with Chrome.

This is what the placeholders look like on Win7 Chrome: 
[image]

Some relevant styles:

```
.field input, .field textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

input, textarea {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 15px;
}

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}

label, input {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <input id="cf-name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

The page is here:

http://dev.metertech.co.uk/contact-us

Anyone faced this issue and know what's going on?

Comment: Yeah, you will need to give us more then that. link? fiddle? or just more code.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the OP with a link.

Comment: Your code by itself works fine without getting the inputs chopped off. It's probably other CSS rules screwing things up.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't blame this on Chrome...

Comment: It works fine on Chrome in other operating systems...

Comment: Take out the `line-height: normal` style or use an actual px value

Comment: Removing `line-height: normal;` seems to fix it. Not sure why.

Comment: Nice, hopefully that does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your fix

```
input {
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: have you ever tried to fit a 28px block inside a 18px hole?

Comment: No, because I know it wouldn't fit. All the more reason to avoid using a 28px block :D

Answer (score 0):

You have set the line-height for the inputs to be `normal`, but if you look at your placeholder pseudo-classes, you set them to be `line-height: 2`. So your placeholder text is trying to occupy more height than the actual height of your inputs, hence the "chopped off" placeholder text.

To fix it, remove the line-height property from the placeholders.

You probably also don't need `line-height:normal` - it is the default.

Comment: If line height is defaulted to "normal" then it is set to 18px which will make your answer incorrect.

Comment: I don't know what language you have been doing, but in CSS, `line-height:normal` is the default. And if you actually read my answer, you'd realise it is a much better solution than one based on "magic numbers". But well, I guess sometimes people just want duct tapes and coat hangers - who cares, right?